# AlertDialog Error on Single Choice Item

Tags: android

I am new in android developement I made a new activity that displays a  Single choice items but I gen an error when I compile.

First I had the dialog Showing up but no Single choice Item was shown, just the title and the message of the builder, then after few tries, none was shown, It get's off he program.

Here is my logcat :

```
05-01 04:59:20.078: E/AndroidRuntime(19456): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-01 04:59:20.078: E/AndroidRuntime(19456): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-01 04:59:20.078: E/AndroidRuntime(19456):    at com.androidtest2.Dialogs.showSecondDialog(Dialogs.java:98)
05-01 04:59:20.078: E/AndroidRuntime(19456):    at com.androidtest2.Dialogs.access$1(Dialogs.java:78)
05-01 04:59:20.078: E/AndroidRuntime(19456):    at com.androidtest2.Dialogs$2.onClick(Dialogs.java:38)
05-01 04:59:20.078: E/AndroidRuntime(19456):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4162)
05-01 04:59:20.078: E/AndroidRuntime(19456):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17082)
05-01 04:59:20.078: E/AndroidRuntime(19456):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-01 04:59:20.078: E/AndroidRuntime(19456):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-01 04:59:20.078: E/AndroidRuntime(19456):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-01 04:59:20.078: E/AndroidRuntime(19456):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
05-01 04:59:20.078: E/AndroidRuntime(19456):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-01 04:59:20.078: E/AndroidRuntime(19456):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-01 04:59:20.078: E/AndroidRuntime(19456):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
05-01 04:59:20.078: E/AndroidRuntime(19456):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
05-01 04:59:20.078: E/AndroidRuntime(19456):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and here is my activity :

```
 public class Dialogs extends Activity {

        private AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialogs);

            Button d1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dialog1);
            Button d2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dialog2);

            d1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    showFirstDialog();

                }
            });

            d2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    showSecondDialog();

                }
            });

        }

        private void showSecondDialog(){
                    // variables
                    AlertDialog.Builder ddialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                    final String[] classArray = {"Mage","Paladin","Guerrier","Druide","Chaman"};

                    // process
                    ddialogBuilder.setTitle("Character's Class");
                    ddialogBuilder.setMessage("Choose your Class");
                    ddialogBuilder.setSingleChoiceItems(classArray, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), classArray[which], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                    });



                    // output
                    AlertDialog dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
                    dialog.show();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you indicate the line that causes the null pointer? We know it's line 98, but what does that translate to in the code snippet you posted above?

Comment: getApplicationContext - may be this is null ??

Comment: Where is the code of `showFirstDialog()` method ?

Comment: Use `Dialogs.this` instead of `getApplicationContext()`. Why? check this Dianne Hackborns quote https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/emSO3dzPb30

Comment: JustSoAmazing `AlertDialog dialog = dialogBuilder.create();` is the line you request, I get no error now, thanx to shylendra response but I still have a little problem, check my comment below shylendra answer

Comment: Kedarnath, I erased it since, it works fine, no need for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See your instance variable name was

> AlertDialog.Builder ddialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());

But you used

> AlertDialog dialog = dialogBuilder.create();

Here the instance variable i.e.,`dialogBuilder` mismatched.
That is why you are getting null pointer exception. So here you need to change that line to

> > AlertDialog dialog = ddialogBuilder.create();

Comment: Thanx, I get no longer an error but there still is a problem though, the  'String[] classArray' is not visible ! I see just the title (Character's Class) and the Message (Choose your Class), Any Idea ?

Comment: Ok I found the answer, it Seems that Buttons, Message and Multiple choice items are mutually exclusive

Answer (score 0):

One more issue you can face is **Unable to add window — token null is not for an application” with getApplication() as context**

To avoid this error you should declare `ddialogBuilder` as given below.

```
AlertDialog.Builder ddialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Dialogs.this);
```